# how to access single value array of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, imap

I want to access single value of array in array for my following code,

**now result:**

```
{"result":[{"msgno":" 1","from":[{"personal":"Blind Mailer","mailbox":"mailerblind","host":"gmail.com"}],"subject":"Testing","date":"Mon, 2 Jan 2017 13:16:21 +0530"}]}
```

**required result:**

```
{"result":[{"msgno":" 1","from":"Blind Mailer","subject":"Testing","date":"Mon, 2 Jan 2017 13:16:21 +0530"}]}
```

**php code:**

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SEEN'); 
$output = '';
$result=array(); 
foreach($emails as $ove) {

$headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$ove);

$emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$ove);

if(!isset($emailStructure->multipart)) {
    array_push($result,array("msgno"=>$headerInfo->Msgno ,"from"=>$headerInfo->from,"subject"=>$headerInfo->subject,"date"=>$headerInfo->date));
} else {   
     array_push($result,array("msgno"=>$ove->msgno,"from"=>$ove->from,"subject"=>$ove->subject,"date"=>$ove->date));
}   
}
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_push` will append items to the array.  Since what you are appending is itself an array you have an array inside an array rather than all values in a single array.

Instead you want to use `array_merge` which will take two arrays and join them together to create a single 1-dimensional array.  See the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php